# Windows XP startup profiling?

Tags: windows-xp, boot

My Windows XP computer is suffering from slow boot times, and although I use the free [Quick Startup](http://www.glarysoft.com/quick-startup/) utility to enable only the programs I want, I still need to know which programs take the longest time to startup, slowing down my entire boot time.

Any profiling app available that lets me see how long each program takes to startup?

Comment: I've used this similar software to delay startups... http://www.r2.com.au/page/products/show/startdelay

I Windows Vista & 7, you have the option to delay starting some services without additional software.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Windows Boot Analyzer](http://www.greatis.com/utilities/bootlogxp/)

Boot Log XP is that you search for troubleshooting Windows boot-up problems in Windows XP.

Boot Log XP creates the new boot log file and allows you to view it visually.

[image]

Note: this isn't free.

Comment: So, my System starts at second 4 all the way to 35. In the mean time other DLLs and exe loads. Is there a way to make System load completely before all the others?

Comment: @SunWKim I have no idea sorry.

Answer (score 2):

[BootVis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BootVis) may help, if you still can download it.

Comment: I was able to download BootVis from Softpedia. It does a pretty good job of analyzing the boot order and when you select the System Optimization feature, it runs a defrag so the files are physically lined up on the hard drive to load in the exact order expected.

It doesn't really look at how you can improve your load times by removing startups, or delaying services like you can with Vista/Windows 7, but if you are stuck in Windows XP, you can improve to some degree. I was able to improve my boot time of 45 seconds to 35 seconds using BootVis.

Answer (score 1):

`xperf` (introduced with Vista) can do the profiling for you, even on Windows XP. It's also free. [This article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/jeff_stokes/archive/2009/12/18/why-do-i-have-long-boot-times.aspx) describes the basic steps, and contains instructions for deploying the WPT to Windows XP:

> The required steps to collect xperf logs on XP / Vista are as follows:
>
> 1. Download & Install the toolkit on a Vista/2008/Windows 7 machine. 
>      The latest version of the Windows Performance Toolkit is part of the Windows 7 SDK (which is a huge download). The following blog has the steps to download the ‘bare minimum’ to get the WPT toolkit.
>      http://blogs.msdn.com/jimmymay/archive/2009/11/24/xperf-install-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt-with-242mb-download-not-2-5gb-windows-7-sdk-part-2.aspx
> 2. Copy the contents of the “C:\Program Files\Microsoft Windows Performance Toolkit”  to a folder on Windows XP (or a USB memory stick).
> 3. Turn off the  “No Execute” or ‘Execute Disable” security option for CPU in the BIOS (or if you cannot find the appropriate BIOS setting, add the following switch to the boot.ini file:  noexecute=alwaysoff)
> 4. Either run xbootmgr from the command line, or use the XPerfUI utility which you can download from our codeplex website: http://xperfui.codeplex.com/
> 5. Copy the resulting .etl file to the Vista machine to use the xperfview GUI to open & analyze it. If a userenv log is generated under %windir%\debug\usermode, it can also be copied to correlate processes & times.

Answer (score 0):

[WinBootInfo 1.01](http://www.clockmod.com/index.php?/products/view/winbootinfo_1.0/)

[image]

> Then WinBootInfo is the perfect solution for you! For only $14.95 (30
>   day trial is FREE) you will get the powerful system boot monitoring
>   tool with following features included:
>
> - Windows Boot Time Logging
> - Detailed information about loaded drivers, applications and system DLLs
> - Each loaded system component is displayed on the detailed time map
> - Tree-View of Loaded Processes sorted in time, with all belonging DLLs/Drivers
> - Different times logged (boot to Login Prompt, Explorer, Session Manager)
> - Detailed CPU utilization tracking during boot, per every CPU core
> - I/O activity tracking during boot
> - System Interrupt / Context Switch tracking during boot
> - Text Log generation and Printing
> - History Feature, for comparing current with the past boot results

Comment: All that's great, but I tried out the demo and it does not show you which program takes how long to startup visually.

Comment: Awh well, glad the other one did work ;-)