# How to reduce Windows XP computer boot time?

Tags: windows-xp, boot

Are there any specific known steps which I could take to make my computer with Windows XP Professional booting faster?

I am interested in speeding up following stages in particular:

- loading the OS (Windows logo, up to the moment login screen appears)
- log in user (from the moment you type your user name and password up to the moment all memory resident programs and services are loaded and the computer is really ready to use)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try profiling your startup time to see what exactly is taking such a long time. This will help you better figure out what to reduce. There's a question regarding this on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/13585/windows-xp-startup-profiling).

Comment: Testing this utility right now, and testing bootvis from Microsoft as well. Besides of things specific to my system I guess there will be some general tips to give (like disabling Java Quick Starter) once I am done.

Comment: @Suma there are always things to improve boot time. Running **msconfig** will show you all the apps that start at boot time. If it's not vital, I suggest you disable it (but check to see what it does before that). With services it's a bit trickier; I suggest you leave them as they are, since stopping the wrong ones can have negative consequences.

Answer (score 2):

The quickest thing you can do is to click Start then run and type "msconfig" go to the Startup tab and disable everything. Reboot and reinstate them one by one until your computer is faster - by using this method, you will be able to see what is taking longest.

You can also go to the services tab and disable there. Services such as AV programs are usually the most to blame for slow start up times.

If you want more control over the startup and see exactly what is running from any location on your system, I highly advise you use the [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) program from Microsoft Sysinternals.

[image]

Comment: Disable services, even AV programs, what a good advice.

Comment: This tool is great to know what is running, but it gives me no idea how much time is consumed by individual items. Boot Profiling utilities seems a lot more useful.

Comment: Sorry, but your question was how to make the computer start faster, not how can I see what processes are taking up what time....

Comment: Yes, but for this knowing what processes are taking time is extremely useful. There are too many processes and services started for me to decide which I perhaps might not need (and disable them). Boot profiler allows me to concentrate on disabling those where I can gain most.

Comment: Then you just upvote and accept the one that helps you the most - in my opinion, it is bad to downvote when someone gives an answer if it is on topic and useful just because someone else is better (I am guessing it was you as it was within a few seconds of your comment)

Comment: Just get angry when I try to help someone it is as if they don't appreciate it...

Comment: I am sorry, I would undo my downvote, but it is no longer possible. I hope you are not really that much angry because of two rep points lost?

Comment: This conversation should be on MSO. No, I couldn't care less about reputation - it is just what it represents. I just think it is bad to down vote someone who helps and gives a valid answer - just because someone else is better... it just looks like you don't appreciate people going to the trouble of trying to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft once created a tool for this: **BootVis**
http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/sysperf/fastboot/default.mspx

Comment: Note: MS no longer offers BootVis for download, but you can find it at many public download sites, including http://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/System-Tweak/BootVis.shtml

Answer (score 0):

A list of utilities which I have found absolutely unnecessary for me, and I guess many users may see the same:

- JQS.exe - Java Quick Start - see [QHacks JQS.exe](http://www.ghacks.net/2008/12/15/jqsexe/) to see how to disable it
- wgatray.exe - Windows Genuine Advantate - I did not find how to disable it safely yet
- ccc.exe - Catalyst Control Center - can be uninstalled

Answer (score 0):

Use [Soluto](http://www.soluto.com/).

[image]

Comment: It seems Soluto might be very handy for WinXP. However, I have changed a computer to Win7 meanwhile and I find Soluto misleading. The computer is ready to use far sooner than Soluto reports, as Win7 have their own delayed starting of background applications, and using Soluto for this brings very little real gain, if any.

Answer (score 0):

After cleaning up run either:

```
rundll32 advapi32.dll,ProcessIdleTasks
```

or

```
defrag C: -b
```

Both defragment boot files in logical order destroyed by each Service Pack.

You might want `pagedfrg.exe` from [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals) to make registry into one fragment and `contig.exe` to defragment disk structures like `MFT$`.